# display content above labels using radio tabs - CSS only?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am trying to display the content ABOVE the tab labels when clicked. Is there a simple way to do this? Maybe using CSS only? When placing the content div above the label the page breaks... Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/shtVe/)

CSS

```
    .tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus varius urna, ac venenatis arcu convallis consequat. In augue est, posuere auctor facilisis varius, dictum ac risus. Donec nibh justo, aliquam sed tempus quis, lobortis sed orci.
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       <div class="content">
           Vivamus id elementum risus. In sit amet mi nulla, ac sollicitudin odio. Phasellus laoreet leo vitae velit lobortis at condimentum odio placerat. Nam sapien eros, accumsan id porttitor a, commodo ut urna. Cras dignissim metus quis enim placerat lobortis.
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           Phasellus scelerisque luctus ligula, a consequat orci posuere rutrum. Sed ipsum nisi, ullamcorper eget fermentum a, dignissim sed dolor. Mauris viverra pretium ante, eu mollis nisi volutpat quis. Nunc neque erat, pharetra in feugiat eget, faucibus id sem. 
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can’t switch those elements in DOM order, because then the selector `~` will not work any more. So your optiones are to either achieve that effect only visually by absolute positioning, using negative margins or the flexbox layout model’s `order` property – or to change the DOM, and use anchor links for the tabs and the `:target` pseudo class to trigger display of the content elements.

Comment: thanks for your help, i'll look into the stuff you've mentioned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your complete design allows for it, you could assign a fixed height and min-width to the content area. Then you will be able to position the tabs by adding a negative value to their `bottom` property.

```
.tab label {
    background: #eee;
    left: 1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    /*--- Updated value ---*/
    bottom: -149px;
}
...
.content {
    background: white;
    left: 0;
   /*--- Updated values ---*/
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 350px;
   /*----*/
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsbin.com/quceviha/1/

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what i was trying to do, however i was using the negative values incorrectly... thank you! :)